Is it feasible to use BERTopic on non-sentence based data?
I would like to create a topic model of the contents of a "Remarks" field in a CRM. There are a couple of hundreds of such entries. They are, more often than not, not whole sentences, just combinations of words (e.g. "customer from the 2024 conference in Zürich", or "hardware vendor, interested in product X")
I am new to topic modelling, but I have built an initial model using BERTopic. However, many of the topics generated are incoherent. May this have to do with the fact that BERTopic is based on sentence embeddings but my source data does not consist of whole sentences?
